# Colnames passed through an apply function R

Tags: r, apply

I am trying to use apply and a user defined function on a data.frame. Inside the function I would like to use the column name (for a title of a plot), but apply seems to strips the column name and passes only a vector. MWE:

```
trialData <- data.frame('a' = rnorm(100),
                        'b' = rnorm(100),
                        'c' = rnorm(100))

someData <- function(dataInput){
  return(colnames(dataInput))
}

dataOutput <- apply(trialData, 2, someData)

print(dataOutput)
```

returns `NULL`. Is there any way of accessing the column name inside the function?

Comment: The *apply functions do not give you access to the "attributes" of the data that is being looped through. There are some roundabout ways to access the colnames from within *apply, but my question is what are you trying to achieve with this code? Based on your post there is no need for the call to `apply`.

Comment: I'm doing quite a lot of things inside my actual function, a few things require the name of the column. For instance, I generate a few figures and I'd like to use the name in the title. I guess if I cant acess the attributes, I'd need to rewrite the function so that it takes a string, and the call to apply so that it takes two arguments.

Comment: First, I consider using lapply to iterate over your columns. Second, instead of passing the dataframe to lapply, pass the column names and then subset from the dataframe for your intended operations.

Comment: lapply(colnames(trialData), function(x) myfun(trialData[, x] )    will return a list object with plots. Then you can loop through the list and call print to draw figures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the commentors I arrived at the below which give me my desired result.

```
trialData <- data.frame('a' = rnorm(100),
                        'b' = rnorm(100),
                        'c' = rnorm(100))

someData <- function(dataInput){
  # lots of code here
  return(
    dataName = colnames(dataInput)
  )
}

dataOutput <- lapply(colnames(trialData), function(x){someData(trialData[x])})

print(dataOutput)
```