# R Keep colnames and rownames when using sapply on a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, apply, sapply

A question was already asked on how keeping colnames in a matrix when applying `apply`, `sapply`, etc. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250209/colnames-passed-through-an-apply-function-r).
But I didn't find how to keep the column **AND** row names of a matrix.

Below an example:

```
mat = matrix(c(as.character(1:4)), nrow = 2)
colnames(mat) = c( 'col1', 'col2' )
rownames(mat) = c( 'row1', 'row2' )
mat = apply(mat,  2,  function(x) as.numeric(paste(x)))
colnames(mat)
rownames(mat)
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15229199/r-rownames-colnames-dimnames-and-names-in-apply) question and it's answer might be worth taking a look at

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can wrap your application in a user-defined function.

```
mat_fun <- function(m){
  m2 <- apply(m,  2,  function(x) as.numeric(paste(x)))
  colnames(m2) <- colnames(m)
  rownames(m2) <- rownames(m)
  return(m2)
}

mat_fun(mat)
#      col1 col2
# row1    1    3
# row2    2    4
```

Comment: Very clever! He had to think. Thank you very much ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you reassign using `[]`, the names are preserved. Unfortunately, this is only useful when you don't want to create a new matrix and also don't want to change the class of the elements (e.g. from character to numeric as in this example)

```
mat[] <- apply(mat,  2,  function(x) 1 + as.numeric(paste(x)))
mat
#      col1 col2
# row1 "2"  "4" 
# row2 "3"  "5"
```

Comment: Thanks for this precision. This method may be very useful on some operations.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Humpelstielzchen's comment, here's my alternative:

```
mat = apply(mat, 2, function(x) setNames(as.numeric(paste(x)), names(x)))
```

Basically, as `apply` is working in row-wise manner (ie, every row is considered separately as a vector) we must name our new vector as we created it... and for that, `setNames` is a wonderful option.